# relisting resulted data.frame respect to input list

Tags: r, dataframe

I feed `inputList` to my custom function, after several workflows(few simple filtration), I end up with data.frame `resultDF`, which needed to be relisted. I used `relist` to make `resultDF` has the same structure of `inputList`, but I got an error. Is there any simplest way of relisting `resultDF`? Can anyone point me out how to make this happen? Any idea? sorry for this simple question.

Here is input data.frame within the list:

```
inputList <- list(
    bar=data.frame(from=c(8,18,33,53),
                   to=c(14,21,39,61), val=c(48,7,10,8)),
    cat=data.frame(from=c(6,15,20,44), 
                   to=c(10,17,34,51), val=c(54,21,14,12)),
    foo=data.frame(from=c(11,43), to=c(36,49), val=c(49,13)))
```

After several workflows, I end up with this data.frame:

```
resultDF <- data.frame(
    from=c(53,8,6,15,11,44,43,44,43),
    to=c(61,14,10,17,36,51,49,51,49),
    val=c(8,48,54,21,49,12,13,12,13)
)
```

I need to relist `resultDF` with the same structure of `inputList`. I used `relit` method, but I got an error.

This is my desired list:

```
desiredList <- list(
    bar=data.frame(from=c(8,53), to=c(14,61), val=c(48,8)),
    cat=data.frame(from=c(6,15,44,44), to=c(10,17,51,51), val=c(54,21,12,12)),
    foo=data.frame(from=c(11,43,43), to=c(36,49,49), val=c(49,13,13))
)
```

How can I achieve `desiredList` ? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: How do you know how those groups are formed from `resultdf` ? I mean how do you know what comes in `bar`, `cat` and `foo` ?

Comment: @RonakShah because I did `unlist` for `inputList` first, then proceed my workflow, at the end, I got `resultDF`, I need to break them as list of data.frame. Giving all detailed workflows would be lengthy.

Comment: oops, maybe I wasn't clear. I am asking about the step from `resultDF` to `desiredList` . how do you know what comes in `bar`, `cat` and `foo` ?

Comment: @RonakShah I look into `resultDF` first, compare to `inputList`, then create manually the imaginative `desiredList`. Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can loop through the 'inputList' and check whether the `paste`d row elements in 'resultDF' are `%in%` `list` elements and use that index to subset the 'resultDF'

```
lapply(inputList, function(x) resultDF[do.call(paste, resultDF) %in% do.call(paste, x),])
```

---

Another option is a `join` and then `split`.  We `rbind` the 'inputList' to a `data.table` with an additional column 'grp' specifying the `list` names, `join` with the 'resultDF' `on` the column names of 'resultDF', and finally `split` the dataset using the 'grp' column

```
library(data.table)
dt <- rbindlist(inputList, idcol = "grp")[resultDF, on = names(resultDF)]
split(dt[,-1, with = FALSE], dt$grp)
```

Comment: Dear akrun, Thanks for your solution. Is there any simplest approach to do this? I afraid using `lapply` could be expensive if `inputList` rather big. Is that possible to make above solution even more simple? Thank you very much.

Comment: @Dan I updated with a join/split method.  It should be more efficient